# netbeans 7.2 search from beginning of the file

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans-7

In older versions of Netbeans, whenever you press CTRL + F and go through the results using `Next` button, after you reach the last result and press `Next` again it would take you to the first result starting from beginning of the file again. Netbeans 7.2 no longer does that. Is there a way to activate it back? Cant find anything in the options...

Additional info: PHP and JS files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the "Wrap Around" checkbox is checked.